# Difficulty inspecting Flutter elements in a Flutter app using Appium Inspector

Tags: flutter, xpath, appium, inspector, selenide

[Appium Inspector Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00vzu.png) I am facing challenges inspecting Flutter elements in my Flutter app using Appium Inspector while using Selenide. When I try to locate elements using accessibility IDs or XPath, I am unable to identify the desired elements. The only option available in Appium Inspector is XPath, but even that is not working. I would like to know the correct approach to inspect Flutter elements and successfully locate them using Selenide.

Description:
I can successfully locate certain elements using Selenide and AppiumBy.accessibilityId. For example, I have used the following code and it works fine:

> Selenide.$(AppiumBy.accessibilityId("Get Started")).click();
> Selenide.$x("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText").click();
> Selenide.$x("//android.view.View[@content-desc="Insurance"]/android.widget.ImageView");

However, when I try to locate other elements using either accessibility IDs or XPath, it doesn't work. For example, I tried to locate an element with the accessibility ID "Ledger" using the following code, but it didn't work:

> SelenideAppium.$(AppiumBy.accessibilityId("Ledger")).click();
> Selenide.$x("//android.view.View[@content-desc="Ledger"]/android.widget.ImageView").click();

I need guidance on the correct approach to inspect Flutter elements in my Flutter app using Appium Inspector and Selenide. I would like to be able to successfully locate the desired elements. Any assistance or potential solutions would be greatly appreciated.